# Azure CLI with Event Hubs

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-cli

i'm currently trying to set up an automatic deployment for my serverless application on azure. The last missing piece for me is to automatically set up a connection between newly created EventHub and Azure Function.

For the automatic deployment I use resource templates with Azure CLI 2.0 and I have no idea how to get a connection string to event hub, in the portal I can find this connection string in event hub's namespace->setting->shared access policies->policy.

But I would like to fetch it with command line, however it seems that event hubs are still not supported in Azure CLI 2.0?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest

Has anybody idea how could I get this connection, so I would have the whole deployment automated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has anybody idea how could I get this connection, so I would have the
>   whole deployment automated?

For now, Azure CLI 2.0 not support Event hub.

You can use Azure PowerShell command `Get-AzureRmEventHubAuthorizationRule` to do it.

More information about PowerShell of Event hub, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.eventhub/?view=azurermps-5.1.1).